# How to multiply 2 fftw_complex arrays

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, fftw

### Heading

Hi,
I'm trying to multiply two arrays of fftw_complex types, how should i do it?

Here's the code:

```
fftw_complex *rInF, *gInF, *bInF;
fftw_complex *rOutF, *gOutF, *bOutF;
for(int i=0;i<m_image->width()*m_image->height();i++)
{


    //realis
    rInF[i][0] = rIn[i][0]*rInMask[i][0] - rIn[i][1]*rInMask[i][1];
    gInF[i][0] = gIn[i][0]*gInMask[i][0] - gIn[i][1]*gInMask[i][1];
    bInF[i][0] = bIn[i][0]*bInMask[i][0] - bIn[i][1]*bInMask[i][1];
    //imaginalis
    rInF[i][1] = rIn[i][1]*rInMask[i][0] + rIn[i][0]*rInMask[i][1];
    gInF[i][1] = gIn[i][1]*gInMask[i][0] + gIn[i][0]*gInMask[i][1];
    bInF[i][1] = bIn[i][1]*bInMask[i][0] + bIn[i][0]*bInMask[i][1];
}
```

I have 2 arrays for each RGB channel(from two images which give us- 2R,2G,2B).

rIn,gIn,bIn and rInMask,gInMask,bInMask are OK. I want to multiply two complex numbers and assign the vaule of multiplication to the rInF, gInF and bInF.

Later I'll make a backward fftw and have convolution in frequency domain.(<- that's not important).

The application just shuts down and doesn't give me any errors.

Comment: There is a ready method called `multiply` for the type you mention, which takes two arrays and return a new one. What else do you need ?

Comment: You should suggest to the developers of `fftw_complex` that they override `operator*`.

Comment: What should I include to multiply that, and how use it? I can't use #include <complex.h>

Comment: Ups... i've forgot to allocate memory for those arrays:rInF=(fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*m_image->width()*m_image->height());